# Constants in views and controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I declare constants in AngularJS so that they can be used both in controllers and HTML. I want to use them like a configuration variable but be able to evaluate them in my views as well. Using $scope or $rootScope seems like an over overkill since these values will never be changed.

Comment: Have you consider [constant service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide#constant)?

Comment: Yes, but is there an easy way to access it form views (HTML)?

Comment: if you want to use them in angular expressions they need to be scoped. Set them all in an object so you only have to scope that object

Comment: Constants are injectable into directives.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup a constant or value:

```
app.constant('myConstant', 'hello');
app.value('myConstant', { name: 'hello'});
```

Then you can inject them into wherever is needed. 
Bind them to your scope so that you can access them in your HTML:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, myConstant) {
     $scope.myConstant = myConstant;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-contorller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myValue.name" />
</div>
```

Comment: But how do I evaluate them in my html file?

Comment: Once you inject them into your controller, you can bind them to your scope.  They are then accessible from your HTML.  Alternatively, you could use the "Controller As" way of binding, where your constants and values are setup as properties of the controller rather than the scope.

Comment: `constant` and `value` service types can both handle primitives and object literals: http://plnkr.co/edit/LfEEwP2RZmOTjreTovfi?p=preview

Comment: The difference is that you can use `constant` values in your $config block, since you're promising the value is fixed: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant